# Is there a way to use a PowerPoint presentation in a node?

Tags: nodes

I've been spending a lot of time trying to find a solution to play a PowerPoint in a node. Converting the file to SWF won't work for me since I need this to also play on mobile. Third-party upload doesn't work either because more than one person will be using this, and we don't want to have any liability in sharing the files to public this needs to be private. This is also why Google docs don't work.

It is crazy that there is no module that will play a PPT on Drupal, being PPT so easy.

Please I need a light here. I'm not a pro in Drupal, and I only have access to the Drupal dashboard. I can't fix any PHP or files either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.drupal.org/project/gdoc_field and field on node to upload and display powerpoint presentation.